# Create procedure in SQL fails

Tags: mysql

At the moment I'm trying to create a procedure in my databse with this query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTitle(title VARCHAR(50), interpret VARCHAR(50), album VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Interpret (Name) VALUES (interpret);
    SET @idInterpret := (SELECT id FROM Interpret WHERE Name = interpret);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Album (Name, Interpret) VALUES (@album, @idInterpret);
    SET @idAlbum := (SELECT id FROM Interpret WHERE Name = album AND Interpret = @idInterpret);

    INSERT INTO Lied (Name, Album, Interpret) VALUES (title, @idAlbum, @idInterpret,);
END;
```

But now I get the following error which doesn't tell my anything:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

Do you have an idea where my mistake is? I use a MySQL server.

Comment: use `DELIMITER //` at top ( and end and reset appropriately )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your problem might just be a delimited.  Second, you are approaching the calculation of the inserted `id` incorrectly.  You should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTitle(title VARCHAR(50), interpret VARCHAR(50), album VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Interpret (Name)
        VALUES (interpret);
    SELECT @idInterpret :-= LAST_INSERT_ID()

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Album (Name, Interpret)
        VALUES (@album, @idInterpret);
    SELECT @idAlbum := LAST_INSERT_ID()

    INSERT INTO Lied (Name, Album, Interpret)
        VALUES (title, @idAlbum, @idInterpret);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also, `set` uses `=`, not `:=`.  The latter is only needed in `SELECT` statements.  And, you had an extra comma in the last `VALUES()` statement.

Comment: But if the insert does not work `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give a wrong id or am I wrong?

Comment: @Cilenco . . . I think it returns `NULL` (or the value is undefined).  However, your code has the `INSERT IGNORE`, which doesn't seem like a good idea.  But it is irrelevant to getting the code to parse and function.

Comment: OKay thank you for that. What would be the alternative to IGNORE? And can you please shortly explain what DELIMITER does?

Comment: @Cilenco . . . `DELIMITER` allows you to use semicolons in the stored procedure.  Read the documentation on the topic.  I would suggest that you remove the `IGNORE` so you can an error if the `INSERT` fails for some reason.  Ignoring areas doesn't result in robust code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTitle(title VARCHAR(50), interpret VARCHAR(50), album VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Interpret (Name) VALUES (interpret);
    SET @idInterpret := (SELECT id FROM Interpret WHERE Name = interpret);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Album (Name, Interpret) VALUES (@album, @idInterpret);
    SET @idAlbum := (SELECT id FROM Interpret WHERE Name = album AND Interpret = @idInterpret);

    INSERT INTO Lied (Name, Album, Interpret) VALUES (title, @idAlbum, @idInterpret,);
END//
delimiter ;
```

For more details please see: [MySQL CREATE PROCEDURE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)